What's the hard layer behind my drywall?
In a 4 year old apartment building with steel studs, I’m using a stud finder on a wall opposite to a hallway to find stud locations. The results of the stud finder are confusing and not consistent with regularly spaced studs. The stud finder works fine on another wall though showing studs over 3” wide, spaced 16” apart.
To understand what’s behind the wall, I planned to use an endoscope. But drilling through the wall I find a hard layer behind the drywall. I drilled another hole further away and not inline with the first hole to find the same hard layer. It is not magnetic and I think it’s likely used for insulation but I'm not sure.
Any way for me to figure out what this is?


Make a larger hole in an inconspicuous spot, at least 3 inches wide, and take a better photo.  3 inches because if it's not a stud wall, you'll better discover what it is.  OR ..  drill three 1/2 inch holes 6 inches apart horizontally and use your borescope in all of them.  If all three them encounter no cavity, it probably isn't a cavity wall.

Judging by the vertical scratches, the hardness, and the colour and the way is spalled around the hole it Looks like CMU to me.
Concrete Masonry Unit
